# MongoDB one-to-many querying

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble with reverse lookup in MongoDB and don't have the words to express what I want to do in a google search.

For example I have a `Client` collection.
An `Order` collection has a reference to `Client` and one to `Salesman`.

Is there a way to:

- Get a list of all `clients` containing an array of their `orders` (given we don't store an array of references in the `client`?
- Get a list of all `clients` whom have dealt with George the `salesman`?

Data would look like

Clients:

```
[
    {_id: ObjectId('c1'), name:'blow', fname: 'joe'},
    {_id: ObjectId('c2'), name:'smith', fname: 'john'},
]
```

Orders:

```
[
    {_id: ObjectId('o1'), item: 'wrench', client: ObjectId('c1'), salesman: ObjectId('s1')},
    {_id: ObjectId('o2'), item: 'monkey wrench', client: ObjectId('c1'), salesman: ObjectId('s1')},
    {_id: ObjectId('o2'), item: 'spanner', client: ObjectId('c1'), salesman: ObjectId('s2')}
]
```

Salesmen:

```
[
    {_id: ObjectId('s1'), name:'smith', fname: 'terry'},
    {_id: ObjectId('s2'), name:'wick', fname: 'john'},
]
```

In a query where I'm listing `clients`, I'd like to see:

```
[
    {_id: ObjectId('c1'), name:'blow', fname: 'joe', orders: [ObjectId('o1'), ObjectId('o2'), ObjectId('o3')]},
    {_id: ObjectId('c2'), name:'smith', fname: 'john', orders: []}
]
```

And in a list of salesmen I'd like to see:

```
[
    {_id: ObjectId('s1'), name:'smith', fname: 'terry', clients: [ObjectId('c1')]},
    {_id: ObjectId('s2'), name:'wick', fname: 'john', clients: [ObjectId('c1')]}
]
```

I've seen the recommendations from MongoDB where in a one-to-many relationship, I shouldn't keep a mutable array of `orders` in `client` and `orders`/`clients` in `salesman`, but I don't know how to perform the sort of "join" I'm after coming from a SQL background.

In a structure where `order` refers to `client` and `salesman` but not vice-versa, how do I get that?

Comment: Can you add an example from input data and expected output?

Comment: Here's some example data and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit late but you can achieve your relation like this:

###### Client query:

- Frist [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the collections
- And then `$project` to output values you want. In this case using `$map` to get only value from each `_id` key into "orders".

```
db.clients.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "client",
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "fname": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "orders": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$orders",
          "in": "$$this._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5GM5NbrwxYa)

###### Salesmen query:

The same idea, use first `$lookup` to do the join and `$map` to get the `_ids`. Also here you can use `$setInteresection` to avoid repeated values.

```
db.salesmen.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "salesman",
      "as": "clients"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "clients": {
        "$setIntersection": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$clients",
            "in": "$$this.client"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T2DJpVGygVU)

###### Other query

And also, to answer te question

> Get a list of all `clients` whom have dealt with George the `salesman`?

You can use two `$lookup` and two `$unwind` like this:

- First `$match` to get only queries about "George the salesman".
- Then join with "orders" collection.
- `$unwind` to get the field `orders.client` and join (`$lookup`) again with the document `collection`.
- `$unwind` again and `$group` without `_id` to get all clients existing.

```
db.salesmen.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "George"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "salesman",
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$orders"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "clients",
      "localField": "orders.client",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "clients"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$clients"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "clients": {
        "$addToSet": "$clients"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U4Ed7GT52_U)

Comment: Sorry for the reciprocally late answer! This question and answer should go right in the official documentation, I'll keep it close for next time I use MongoDB.